# CMake builds shared library to `.dylib` on Mac but `.so` on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to using CMake as required by an external library. My program written in C++17 compiles to a shared library intended to be used via a Python API using `ctypes`.

When I build on my mac, the resulting file is a `.dylib`. But when I compile on our Linux cluster (Ubuntu), I get a `.so`.

This is only a problem since I need to tell python the extension of the library. Swapping out the name in Python yields the same behavior. How can I make it to build to the same extension/library type on both platforms?

Here is an abbreviated CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
project(BICS_ABM)
add_subdirectory(igraph)
add_subdirectory(googletest)

enable_testing()


# Add testing 
enable_testing()

add_library(BICS_ABM_lib SHARED # MODULE 
    src/BICS_ABM.h 
    src/print_attributes.cpp
    src/decrement.cpp
    src/set_sick.cpp
    src/transmit.cpp
    src/distribute_vax.cpp
    src/history.cpp
    src/BICS_ABM.cpp 
    src/py_defs.cpp
    src/params.cpp
    src/mixing.cpp
    )


add_executable(BICS_ABM_tests
    src/tests/tests_main.cpp
    src/tests/decrement_tests.cpp
    )

file(COPY data DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(BICS_ABM_lib PUBLIC igraph)
target_link_libraries(BICS_ABM_tests PUBLIC BICS_ABM_lib PRIVATE gtest gtest_main )

include(GoogleTest)
add_test(Vax_tests BICS_ABM)
add_test(DataTests BICS_ABM)
add_test(DecrementTests BICS_ABM)
```

Comment: The extension names are the standart according to the OS. On Windows it would be dll. Just check in python what OS you use and change the extension accordingly.

Comment: It's definitely an odd request to want to go against the OS conventions. Better to account for multi-platform on your side of things than to try to bend the platforms to your whims.

Comment: I see— my fundamental misunderstanding of how libraries work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make it to build to the same extension/library type on both platforms?

As for the file extensions, you can either deal with this on the Python side of things using [`platform.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system), or you can set the [`CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) to some platform-independent value in your CMake configure command with the [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D) option format.

As for the file type, different platforms support different shared library binary formats and they tend to be largely platform specific. As far as I'm aware, for example, you can't just plop a DLL onto a Mac or Linux machine and expect it to just work.

You may also be interested in [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html), [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), and [nanobind](https://github.com/wjakob/nanobind).

Comment: I see— better to include a flag for system, then load the corresponding library. Thank you!